# How to print printable object info in python

Tags: python, object

See:

```
>>> class A:
...     a = 3
... 
>>> tmp=A()
>>> tmp
<__main__.A instance at 0xb7340c2c>
>>> A
<class __main__.A at 0xb733c26c>
>>> tmp.a
3
```

I want tmp.a also have the output like 'tmp' and 'A', is that possible?

Please notice this like tmp not in tmp. So what I want will be:

```
>>> tmp.a
<int tmp.a at ...>
```

Comment: not without binding `tmp.a` to something else ..

Answer (score 4):

Each object can have a `__str__` and you can also define a `__repr__` method, which will be printed.

```
>>> class A(object):
...     a = 3
...     def __str__(self):
...         return repr(self)+': a: %d' % self.a
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'A object with id %d ' % id(self)
...
>>> b=A()
>>> b
A object with id 4340531472
>>> print b
A object with id 4340531472 : a: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `tmp.a` is an integer object. It will be displayed like any other integer object. You can however define use a function to get a representation for `a`.

```
class A:
    a = 3
    def repr_a(self):
        return repr(self) + ': a: ' + str(self.a)
```

The 'printable info' for any object is actually controlled by the `__repr__` or `__str__` function. So, you can simply define that.

```
class A:
    a = 3
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Class A: a = ' + str(self.a)
```